# Chainlink Keeper registration from Smart Contract failing on Polygon Mumbai

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-keepers

I'm trying to register upkeeps from my smart contract. I started by using the template for Chainlink Automation Compatible given in the [docs](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/compatible-contracts/). Then I deployed the `UpkeepIDConsumerExample` contract given in the [docs](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/register-upkeep/#testnet-parameters).

I have only added these two lines to the `UpkeepIDConsumerExample` contract,

```
    receive() external payable {}

    // Fallback function is called when msg.data is not empty
    fallback() external payable {}
```

The `UpkeepIDConsumerExample` is deployed to mumbai and is funded with $LINK and $MATIC.

These are my constructor args,

`KeeperRegistrar2_0`:`0x57A4a13b35d25EE78e084168aBaC5ad360252467`
`KeeperRegistry2_0`:`0xE16Df59B887e3Caa439E0b29B42bA2e7976FD8b2`
`Link Token`:`0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB`

Now when I try to call `registerAndPredictID` function, I end up getting this error,

**Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }**

I tried to check with other docs and stackoverflow but no positive results

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you found an issue with the docs. It'll be fixed soon. Until then, here is a [sample contract](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x72882fb944c17dbb1f0428fd3819e7d6a2375567#code#F1#L1) you can check out with the revised code and values

[This transaction](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x03f4ed1fabe6a12a8f150bc8152596c13814af20aa4f941e49c1b0567476165e) shows it working.

**One thing to note**
You must fund the contract you deploy `UpkeepIDConsumerExample` with LINK. If the contract doesn't have any, when you call `registerAndPredictID`, you will see the `Gas estimation error`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code from the docs, but it seems to predict incorrect keeperID.

[Here](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/0x35CE5870B2Ec7BaAe80013fA039A7226150856C4#code) is the contract on Avalanche testnet.

[Here](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/tx/0xad3f329712f606ad982082fb8a5d97124292b4ff498fcdb125d59b652c0b9872) is the transaction of registration new keeper.

The keeperID that was generated in the contract is `57952118558222458575856572226220980248969724156526342114946102634652182490725`
but in fact, the keeper was registered with the id `111802081932340802689174832544601047850748175357678603218220808766025723091259`according to the events logs.